# GitHub projects for a GitHub org I am admin for is showing on my CV

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, cv

I am a GitHub administrator for the Mozilla GitHub org, and I have just updated my CV. All of the Mozilla projects have appeared in my CV, projects I have not worked on.

I don't really want to have to go delete all of them, since there are over 250 projects for the org. It should ask if I really want the org projects.

Comment: When you import projects from GitHub, you should be able to see all the projects that it's going to import.  You can either import just the ones you want, or click the "Import All" button.  If this isn't what you see then we have a bug...

Answer (score 6):

I’ve removed the Mozilla projects from your CV. You can re-add any that you might like.

We’ll work on the interface…thanks!